# How could i filter the listview using baseadapter

Tags: android, search, baseadapter

I am trying to filter the listview but getfilter method is not working,

here is the code:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    mHistoryAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);   
}
```

i have added the method in baseadapter also

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    return null;
}
```

but its not working..could somebody help me out..@Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328955/creating-getfilter-for-baseadapter-for-object-titles. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html. define a custom filter

Comment: @Raghunandan i have tried to add that but getting error

Comment: what is the error. post the stack trace.

Comment: Every change you may filter the listview content manually.

Comment: @Raghunandan i have the arraylist of data how could i filter that

Comment: @priya you can check this example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816243/search-in-listview-with-edittext/15367403#15367403

Comment: @Raghunandan i have tried ..i didn't get can you help me out

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/. check this. what is the difficulty?

Comment: @Raghunandan i need to check sting basis from arraylist but i am getting error

Answer (score 39, accepted):

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView mListView;
private CustomAdapter mCustomAdapter;
private EditText mEditText;
private ArrayList<Contacts> _Contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
        contacts.setId(""+i);
        contacts.setName("Name "+i);
        _Contacts.add(contacts);
    }


    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, _Contacts);
    mListView.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);

    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            mCustomAdapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

private ArrayList<Contacts> _Contacts;
private Activity context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ValueFilter valueFilter;
private ArrayList<Contacts> mStringFilterList;

public CustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Contacts> _Contacts) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this._Contacts = _Contacts;
    mStringFilterList =  _Contacts;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     getFilter();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _Contacts.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return _Contacts.get(position).getName();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView tname, tplace;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        holder.tname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.tplace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.tname.setText("" + _Contacts.get(position).getName());
    holder.tplace.setText("" + "" + _Contacts.get(position).getId());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(valueFilter==null) {

        valueFilter=new ValueFilter();
    }

    return valueFilter;
}
private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

    //Invoked in a worker thread to filter the data according to the constraint.
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
        if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0){
            ArrayList<Contacts> filterList=new ArrayList<Contacts>();
            for(int i=0;i<mStringFilterList.size();i++){
                if((mStringFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
                    contacts.setName(mStringFilterList.get(i).getName());
                    contacts.setId(mStringFilterList.get(i).getId());
                    filterList.add(contacts);
                }
            }
            results.count=filterList.size();
            results.values=filterList;
        }else{
            results.count=mStringFilterList.size();
            results.values=mStringFilterList;
        }
        return results;
    }


    //Invoked in the UI thread to publish the filtering results in the user interface.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        _Contacts=(ArrayList<Contacts>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

Contacts.java

```
public class Contacts {

private String name;
private String id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

This is a sample project code. Use this code this will really help you

Comment: Your code is Initializing Contact twice inside the Filter Class, Instead use this directly filterList.add(mStringFilterList.get( index ));

Comment: Working Perfect. Just modified code with my requirements. Thumbs Up.

Comment: It filters the list but does not return to original state when deleting chars one by one.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot here, but I'm having trouble now in passing a listview item to another activity he sends another item.

Comment: @rodrigo.oliveira you need to use mCustomAdpter.getItem(position) in the List view Item Click listener for getting the Correct value.Hope this will help.

Comment: Works perfect!! Thanks a lot

Comment: HIii @RenjithKrishnan. I follow same code. But i am getting this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter deyapay.bodaty.com.sampledisplay.Splitadapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference. at this place mCustomAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString()); Why it is occuring?

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Answer (score 6):

Here you go. A simple baseadapter (no view recycling) that will display, and filter, a list of some custom arbitary object.  In this example Object.name is the field we will use to filter.

1) In your activity, (or) where you create your **ListView**, enable text filtering:

```
class MyObject {
    public String name;
}
List<MyObject> myData = ArrayList<>();

listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

2) As you already noted, in a textwatcher of an Edittext, trigger the filter on the **ListAdapter**:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    listadapter.getFilter().filter(s);   
}
```

3) in your baseadapter, `implement Filterable`.  And store two copies of the data, one original, and one filtered. *Be sure to access the filtered data throughout the BaseAdapter, not the unfiltered data*

```
public class FilterableListAdapterExample extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private List<MyObject> mData; //the original data
private List<MyObject> mDataFiltered;//the filtered data
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public FilterableListAdapterExample(Context context, List<MyObject> data) {
    mData = data;
    mDataFiltered=data;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView= mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
    TextView textview=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_textview);
    //note: we access mDataFiltered, not mData
    textview.setText(mDataFiltered.get(position).name); 
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataFiltered.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                //no constraint given, just return all the data. (no search)
                results.count = mData.size();
                results.values = mData;
            } else {//do the search
                List<MyObject> resultsData = new ArrayList<>();
                String searchStr = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                for (MyObject o : mData)
                    if (o.name.toUpperCase().startsWith(searchStr)) resultsData.add(o);
                results.count = resultsData.size();
                results.values = resultsData;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mDataFiltered = (ArrayList<MyObject>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Hii @Mtl Dev. I follow same code. But i am getting this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter deyapay.bodaty.com.sampledisplay.Splitadapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference. at this place mCustomAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString()); Why it is occuring?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't created the object "mCustomAdapter" before trying to use it.

Comment: No,I created the object for the adapter class

Comment: Check if it was successfully created, by testing to see if your object `==null`

Answer (score 4):

Please try following code it may helpful for you:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity 
{

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> mOriginalValues;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getModel());
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        EditText filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterText);

        // Add Text Change Listener to EditText
        filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
            {
                // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
            {
            }
        });
    }

    private List<String> getModel() {
        list.add("Linux");
        list.add("Windows7");
        list.add("Suse");
        list.add("Eclipse");
        list.add("Ubuntu");
        list.add("Solaris");
        list.add("Android");
        list.add("iPhone");
        list.add("Windows XP");
        return list;
    }

// Adapter Class            
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable 
{

    List<String> arrayList;      
    List<String> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> arrayList) 
    {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder 
    {
        TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listTxt);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(arrayList.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() 
    {
        Filter filter = new Filter() 
        {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) 
            {

                arrayList = (List<String>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) 
            {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                List<String> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) 
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                }

                /********
                 * 
                 *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                 *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
                 *
                 ********/
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) 
                {

                    // set the Original result to return  
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalValues;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) 
                    {
                        String data = mOriginalValues.get(i);
                        if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) 
                        {
                            FilteredArrList.add(data);
                        }
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;
                }
                return results;
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this is help full for me.

Answer (score 2):

Implement Filterable in your baseadapter class.

[image: listview with search]
[image: search listview]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String names[] = {"Apple","Banana","Kiwi","Oranges","Watermelon"};
String emails[] = {"This is apple","This is banana","This is kiwi","This is oranges","This is watermelon"};
int images[] = {R.drawable.apple,R.drawable.banana,R.drawable.kiwi,R.drawable.oranges,R.drawable.watermelon};

List<ItemsModel> itemsModelList = new ArrayList<>();

ListView listView;

CustomAdapter customAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);


    for(int i = 0;i < names.length;i++){

        ItemsModel itemsModel = new ItemsModel(names[i],emails[i],images[i]);

        itemsModelList.add(itemsModel);

    }

     customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(itemsModelList,this);

    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu,menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchView);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            Log.e("Main"," data search"+newText);

            customAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);



            return true;
        }
    });


    return true;

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if(id == R.id.searchView){

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<ItemsModel> itemsModelsl;
    private List<ItemsModel> itemsModelListFiltered;
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(List<ItemsModel> itemsModelsl, Context context) {
        this.itemsModelsl = itemsModelsl;
        this.itemsModelListFiltered = itemsModelsl;
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemsModelListFiltered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemsModelListFiltered.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_items,null);


        TextView names = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView emails = view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.images);

        names.setText(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).getName());
        emails.setText(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).getEmail());
        imageView.setImageResource(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).getImages());

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("main activity","item clicked");
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ItemsPreviewActivity.class).putExtra("items",itemsModelListFiltered.get(position)));

            }
        });

        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    filterResults.count = itemsModelsl.size();
                    filterResults.values = itemsModelsl;

                }else{
                    List<ItemsModel> resultsModel = new ArrayList<>();
                    String searchStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                    for(ItemsModel itemsModel:itemsModelsl){
                        if(itemsModel.getName().contains(searchStr) || itemsModel.getEmail().contains(searchStr)){
                            resultsModel.add(itemsModel);

                        }
                         filterResults.count = resultsModel.size();
                            filterResults.values = resultsModel;
                    }


                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                itemsModelListFiltered = (List<ItemsModel>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

}

You can a full tutorial on how to implement listview with search and onItemClickListener here:

[Listview with search/filter and onItemClickListener](https://youtu.be/8QDTiOUOfKQ?sub_confirmation=1)

[Source files](https://github.com/larntech/listview-with-search.git)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need of getfilter() method over here

```
ArrayList<YourDataModel> data;
.
.
.
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<YourDataModel>() {
@Override
public int compare(YourDataModel data1, YourDataModel data2) {
      if( data1.getDistance() < data2.getDistance() )
         return 1;
      else
         return 0;
}
});
.
.
.
ListView lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, data);
lvData.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and use `notifydatachange` method whenever you want to update it