# Filter Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, filter

I have a list view with items and sub items in each row.  I have an EditText field that I want to use to filter the list as text is typed.  I want to be able to search the items and sub items.  Can someone point me in the right direction on how I can do this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

public class FarmMarketList extends RSFM
{
    ListView marketList;
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    EditText listSearch;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.farm_market_list);
        marketList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listFarmMarkets);
        listSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.listSearch);

        for(Marker m : list)
        {
            titles.add(m.getTitle());
            addresses.add(m.getSnippet());
        }

        List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++)
        {
            Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
            datum.put("title", titles.get(i));
            datum.put("subtitle", addresses.get(i));
            data.add(datum);
        }

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(FarmMarketList.this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"title", "subtitle"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
        marketList.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

        // Row Selection
        marketList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {
                TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                TextView text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

                Intent i = new Intent(FarmMarketList.this, FarmMarketDetails.class);
                i.putExtra("selectedTitle", text1.getText());
                i.putExtra("selectedAddress", text2.getText());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT: I added this code, but it cause the app to crash when I start typing in the EditText field.

```
listSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
            {
                FarmMarketList.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Comment: I would suggest [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete) and [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android

Comment: Find solution using this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720481/how-could-i-filter-the-listview-using-baseadapter/20743661#20743661

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by adding

```
marketList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

and changing the line in the onTextChange() method to

```
FarmMarketList.this.simpleAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
```

Comment: Hey can you paste the whole code, it could help me a lot.