# Filters on adapters in android

Tags: android, listview, search, adapter

I have a list view and i am populating data in it using

searchList.setAdapter(new DirectoryListAdapter());

where DirectoryListAdapter is my adapter extending base adapter.When i do a search on one of the items-employee_name what should go in my search text box.I tired this code but doesn't work.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

    ((DirectoryListAdapter)adapter).filter(text);
    }
```

What should go in the onTextChanged method.Base adapter code
public class DirectoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
ViewHolder holder;

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;
    public TextView nearestEntranceText;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    int len = MasterData.getInstance().getTenantList().size();
    return len;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View directoryItemView = convertView;

    if (directoryItemView == null) {
        directoryItemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate (R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder ();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) directoryItemView.findViewById (R.id.itemTextView);
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) directoryItemView.findViewById (R.id.logoImageView);
        viewHolder.nearestEntranceText = (TextView) directoryItemView.findViewById (R.id.closestEntranceTextView);
        directoryItemView.setTag (viewHolder);
        holder = viewHolder;
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) directoryItemView.getTag();
    }

    TenantItem item = (TenantItem) MasterData.getInstance().getTenantList().get(position);

    final String noLogoCheckStr = parent.getContext().getString (R.string.web_service_no_logo_comparsion_string);
    final String fetchLink = item.getTenantLogoURL();

    ListItemLayout layoutItem = (ListItemLayout) directoryItemView;
    layoutItem.tenantItemObj = item;
    /*
    layoutItem.tenantID = item.getTenantID();
    if (item.getHasMultipleEntries()) {
        layoutItem.tenantIDList = item.getTenantIDList();
    }
    // layoutItem.tenantIDList = item.getTenantList
    */

    if (fetchLink.contains (noLogoCheckStr)) {
        Picasso.with (parent.getContext())
            .load(R.drawable.placeholder_logo)
            .into(holder.image);
    } else {
        Picasso.with (parent.getContext())
            .load(fetchLink)
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder_logo)
            .into(holder.image);
    }

    holder.text.setText(item.getTenantName());
    if (item.getHasMultipleEntries()) {
        holder.nearestEntranceText.setText (R.string.tenant_multiple_location_label);
    } else {
        holder.nearestEntranceText.setText (item.getTenantLocation());
    }
    return directoryItemView;
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720481/how-could-i-filter-the-listview-using-baseadapter/20743661#20743661

Comment: hi,Thanks for the reply.I already have a base adapter,so for this code     mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, _Contacts) which contains the data.Here is my code for base adapter.How do i reference to this adapter in form of mCustomAdapter.I am pasting my code for base adapter.

Comment: There's a lot more to it, have you looked closely at how the filtering works in that answer?