# Android ListView SearchView

Tags: android, listview, filter, searchview

I created an ListView which is filled by SQLite Database. 
In my App you can add books to a database and you can view the booklist in the BookDataListActivity 
Now I would like to implement a SearchView to filter the books. I used this Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9yC8XGaSv4&list=PLfBjz1j1UV9kdwpvU1YGsjKoNxOtoKTCs&index=1

But it doesnt work. 
Following my code. Hopefully you can help me.

```
package com.kasutwentyseven.gui4selfshelf.Books;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kasutwentyseven.gui4selfshelf.R;

public class BookDataListActivity extends Activity {
public ListView booklistView;
public SearchView searchView;
public SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabaseBooks;
public BookDBHelper bookDBHelper;
public Cursor cursor2;
public BookListDataAdapter bookListDataAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.book_data_list_layout);

    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Lobster.ttf");

    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_yourbooks);
    myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    booklistView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.book_list_view);
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);

    bookListDataAdapter = new BookListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_book_layout);
    booklistView.setAdapter(bookListDataAdapter);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            bookListDataAdapter.getFilter().filter(text);
            return false;
        }
    });

    bookDBHelper = new BookDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabaseBooks = bookDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor2 = bookDBHelper.getInformations(sqLiteDatabaseBooks);
    if(cursor2.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            String booktitle, bookauthor,bookdate, bookrating, bookshelf;

            booktitle = cursor2.getString(0);
            bookauthor = cursor2.getString(1);
            bookdate = cursor2.getString(2);
            bookrating = cursor2.getString(3);
            bookshelf = cursor2.getString(4);

            BookDataProvider bookDataProvider = new BookDataProvider(booktitle, bookauthor, bookdate, bookrating, bookshelf);
            bookListDataAdapter.add(bookDataProvider);

        }while(cursor2.moveToNext());
    }
    booklistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });

}
}
```

How do I implement a Filter?

EDIT: As asked the BookListAdapter

```
package com.kasutwentyseven.gui4selfshelf.Books;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.kasutwentyseven.gui4selfshelf.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BookListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable{

List booklist = new ArrayList();


public BookListDataAdapter(Context context,int resource) {
super(context, resource);
}

static class BookLayoutHandler {
    TextView BOOKTITLE, BOOKAUTHOR, BOOKDATE, BOOKRATING, BOOKSHELF;
}
@Override
public void add (Object object){
super.add(object);
    booklist.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return booklist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return booklist.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row1= convertView;

    BookLayoutHandler bookLayoutHandler;
    if(row1 == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)    this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_book_layout, parent, false);
        bookLayoutHandler = new BookLayoutHandler();
        bookLayoutHandler.BOOKTITLE = (TextView) row1.findViewById(R.id.text_book_title);
        bookLayoutHandler.BOOKAUTHOR = (TextView) row1.findViewById(R.id.text_book_author);
        bookLayoutHandler.BOOKDATE = (TextView) row1.findViewById(R.id.text_book_date);
        bookLayoutHandler.BOOKRATING = (TextView) row1.findViewById(R.id.text_book_rating);
        bookLayoutHandler.BOOKSHELF = (TextView) row1.findViewById(R.id.text_book_shelf);
        row1.setTag(bookLayoutHandler);
    }else{
        bookLayoutHandler = (BookLayoutHandler) row1.getTag();

    }
    BookDataProvider bookDataProvider = (BookDataProvider) this.getItem(position);
    bookLayoutHandler.BOOKTITLE.setText(bookDataProvider.getBooktitle());
    bookLayoutHandler.BOOKAUTHOR.setText(bookDataProvider.getBookauthor());
    bookLayoutHandler.BOOKDATE.setText(bookDataProvider.getBookdate());
    bookLayoutHandler.BOOKRATING.setText(bookDataProvider.getBookrating());
    bookLayoutHandler.BOOKSHELF.setText(bookDataProvider.getBookshelf());
    return row1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `BookListDataAdapter`. You need to need implement filter mechanism there

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html. ArrayAdapter has getFilter method. But you are implementing Filterable interface. Look @ Custom Filter implementation @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122848/custom-getfilter-in-custom-arrayadapter-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will try to implement it later the day. 
To I have to implement the answer of your link into my DatabaseAdapter?

Comment: I do not get it to run. Any more Infos @Raghunandan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328955/creating-getfilter-for-baseadapter-for-object-titles. lots of samples on stackoverflow